# Update WPF application using console application that will call to the windows service

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-services, console-application

Hi stackoverflow masters. What i want trying to solve is to update my WPF application, I have 3 programs WPF applcation, console application and windows service. What it does was my WPF application calls my console application and my console application send a command to the windows service, my windows service will kill the process of my WPF application and do the update and my console application will run my WPF application again. Now, the updating part in windows service is working, but i have a problem with my console application since the WPF application calls my console application every time the user open it and it loops forever. I know there are problems with my console app.

Thanks in advance masters. :)

so here's my code.

```
try
{
_log.Info("Checking for new update.");
int wpfAppExecuteCommand;
string defaultpath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\WPF Application";
string wpfAppInfoPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "WPF\\WPFAppInfo.txt");
string[] txtFile = File.ReadAllLines(wpfAppInfoPath);

if (txtFile.Count() > 0)
{
    _wpfAppInfo = txtFile[0];

    switch (_wpfAppInfo)
    {
        case "WPF Application":
            wpfAppExecuteCommand = 150;
            _wpfSoftwareLocation = Path.Combine(defaultpath, "WPF Application.exe");
            break;
        default:
            wpfAppExecuteCommand = 0;
            break;
    }

    using (var service = new ServiceController("Update Checker API Service"))
    {
        if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        {
            _log.Debug("Service is running.");
            service.ExecuteCommand(wpfAppExecuteCommand);
        }
        else
        {
            _log.Error("Service is not running.");
        }
    }
}

_log.Debug("Please wait..");
_stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
_stopwatch.Start();

bool checking = true;

while (checking)
{
    if (_stopwatch.Elapsed > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
    {
        if (!_oneMin)
        {
            _oneMin = true;
            _log.Warn("Installing udpate is taking too long, please wait..");
        }
    }
    else if (_stopwatch.Elapsed > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
    {
        if (!_fiveMin)
        {
            _fiveMin = true;
            _log.Warn("Installing udpate is taking too long, please wait..");
        }
    }
    else if (_stopwatch.Elapsed > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
    {
        if (!_tenMin)
        {
            _tenMin = true;
            _isTimerOn = true;
            _log.Warn(".");
        }
    }

    if (File.Exists(_resultTxt))
    {
        _log.Trace("File exist. Read if is Success");
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(_resultTxt);

        if (lines[0].Equals("Success"))
        {
            _log.Trace("Checks if the Software.exe exist");
            if (File.Exists(_wpfSoftwareLocation))
            {
                string runMsiExecBatchFile = Path.Combine(_batchFileDefaultFolder, "RunMsiExec.bat");

                //Deleting the batch file used by windows service.
                if (File.Exists(runMsiExecBatchFile))
                {
                    File.Delete(Path.Combine(_batchFileDefaultFolder, "RunMsiExec.bat"));
                    _log.Info("RunMsiExec.bat file deleted.");
                }
                else
                {
                    _log.Warn("RunMsiExec.bat not found");
                }

                _openWpfApp = true;
                checking = false;
                _stopwatch.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                _log.Error("Software.exe not exist");
                _stopwatch.Stop();
                checking = false;
            }

        }
        else if (lines[0].Equals("The current version is up to date"))
        {
            _log.Info("The current version is up to date");
            _openWpfApp = true;
            checking = false;
            _stopwatch.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            _log.Error(lines[0]);
            checking = false;
            _stopwatch.Stop();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _log.Debug("Result text not found.");
    }
}

if (_openWpfApp)
{
    _log.Info("Open WPF application software.");
    Process.Start(_wpfSoftwareLocation);
}
else
{
    _log.Info("Unable to open the Wpf application software.");
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
_log.Error(ex);
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Doesn't [ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-manage-updates-for-a-clickonce-application) fit your needs?

Comment: Hi @vasily.sib thanks for this, I didn't try that before. :)

Comment: WPF app sends a command to the service and gets killed by the service as a result? Why not having the WPF application gracefully exit after requesting the service to install the new version of the application?
Also, I see repeated code with "take too long" messages that could be avoided. Also the messages could say "took more than 1, 5 or 10 minutes" instead of take too long.

Comment: @Tarik thanks for this, noted with the messages. :)  That's a good idea that the WPF exit itseft after requesting to the service. Hmm. I was thinking because the windows service has a different process with the UI, that is why I created a console application so that after the installation i can re-run my WPF application using the console application. That's why i didn't direct the WPF to my service, because if i run my WPF app inside my windows service i can see it on my task manager but no UI and its run under the "Background Processes".

Comment: @vasily.sib and Tarik. so much appreciated your answers. :)

Comment: What about launching the installation process and exit immediately? Alternatively, you can create a batch file that launches the MSI and restart your application. You launch the batch file and exit immediately. You can add a wait in the batch file to give time to your  application to exit.
I would also like to point out that you may want to avoid ad-hoc deployment mechanisms such as these. Why not look at the best practices?

Comment: What I did was, in my windows service I created auto generated batch file with the command of 
string[] msiExecCommand = { "msiexec.exe /i \"" + installerPathLocation + "\" /qb-!" };
File.WriteAllLines(_runMsiExecPathLocation, msiExecCommand);
and kill my WPF application in the task manager using the Process.Kill(). 
Before i run the batch file that launches the MSI for silent installation.

I didn't try to add wait in my batch file. I should search for that. Alright @Tarik noted for that i should avoid ad-hoc deployment and look for best practice. thanks for this. -newbie here